# how to build an iterator over two containers in a chained fashion

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to provide an iterator that iterates over contents of 2 containers.

For example, I would like to hide the fact that the nodes of a polyline are stored in two containers (for implementation purposes):

```cpp
struct PolyLine {
private:
    vector<Point*> m_head_nodes;
    vector<Point*> m_tail_nodes;

public:
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
};

Polyline poly; 
cout << "contents of poly:" << endl;
for(Point *p : poly) 
   cout << p << endl;
```

The iterator should iterate the m_head_nodes first, then the m_tail_nodes.

**Q1:** Could you demonstrate how to set up the Iterator object?

- How do you implement the operator++ at the point where you cross from the first container to the second?

**Q2:** what if, say the 2nd container was, say,  a `std::list` ?

- What construct do you use to represent the current 'position' iterator?
- How do you represent the `end()` ?

---

I have tried an implementation like the following,

```cpp
struct Iterator
{
    PolyLine &m_parent;
    vector<Point*>::iterator m_it;

    Iterator(PolyLine &parent_container)
        : m_parent(parent_container) {
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        if (m_it == m_parent.m_head_nodes.end())
            m_it = m_parent.m_tail_nodes.begin();
        else
            ++m_it;
        return *this;
    }

    Point * operator* () {
         return *m_it;
    }
};

bool operator== (Iterator &one, Iterator &other) {
    return one.m_it == other.m_it;
}

Iterator Polyline::begin() {
    Iterator o(this);
    o.m_it = m_head_nodes.begin();
    return o;
}

Iterator Polyline::end() {
    Iterator o(this);
    o.m_it = m_tail_nodes.end();
    return o;
}
```

but I am not keen on keeping a pointer to the `PolyLine` class.

Plus, I don't know what to keep as an `m_it` in case the 2nd container is a, say,  `std::list`.

Comment: Can you simply merge `m_head_nodes` and `m_tail_nodes` and store a single container instead?

Comment: First, decide what you want your iterator to do. Then implement as much of that as you can. Then ask us about a part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Some range libraries (as range-v3) have concat view's.

Comment: If writing that iterator yourself: You most likely would need a reference to the outer container, an iterator of the latter and an iterator of the inner container. `operator++` would first increment inner iterator, if that one reaches `outer->end()`, it would increment the outer iterator and, if not yet reached outer's end, set the inner iterator to `outer->begin()`. Equality would compare first outer, then, if equal, inner iterators – with special handling for outer already being at end, of course.

Comment: `Vector<point*>` is a bad idea. Better store simply as `vector<point>` - requires less memory and much better performance. Second, why not store heads and tails together instead of separate vectors? Like double length `vector<point>` or `vector<pair<point, point> >`. With this you have no reason to create odd iterators.

Comment: @ALX23z *'bad idea'* – not always: `std::vector<Point> allPoints; std::vector<Point*> someSubset;` *can* be meaningful, depending on use case...

Comment: @vahancho : the whole point of my question is about providing *one* iterator for a struct that has its contents shared across *many* containers. The iterator is meant to be a way for clients of 'Polyline' to access the contents of 'Polyline' without knowing its underlying data structure. I used the 'Polyline' as an example, so we can focus on iterating two containers sequentially. Refactoring the data structure is not an option.

Comment: @Beta: I hope my snippet helps in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aconcagua `vector<int>` or simply copy into another `vector<point>` to represent a subset depending on usage: former for modification and keeping track of data and latter for usage. These methods are safer (what if you add elements to the vector?) and more efficient. So this 'not always' is almost always.

Comment: I find the question pretty darn clear.

Comment: @GrimFandango this depends on the order you want. You could either increment one till you reach the end and then increment the other one. Or you could alternate. Either way I do not recommend doing so, since user might add elements to the structure while iterating over it which will lead to odd behavior. Better let user have an access function and figure out on their own how to iterate over it.

Comment: @Aconcagua: you are the only one who has understood what my aim is. Is there a way of achieving it without the iterator carrying so much data? Can the iterator be independent of the parent structure or the containers it iterates ?

Comment: You probably could have a templated custom Iterator, based on the type of the two containers' iterator. Instead of storing a pointer to the Polyline, you could store the (templated) end of the first container and the begin of the second container. But you'd have to address what happens when the user change those

Comment: @ALX23z, what you're describing can happen even if you have one container: if you add stuff to the container while iterating, you invalidate the iterator. Also, since *I* am creating the Iterator, I am setting up the order of iteration. I can even make it behave like a *const_iterator*.

Comment: @Jeffrey, +1: that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @GrimFandango in C++20 you could write it in a coroutine. Currently, why not simply write a template function `ApplyToAll(Lambda)`?

Comment: @GrimFandango *'without the iterator carrying so much data'* – At very least, you'd need two iterators. `++inner; if(inner == outer->end()) { ++outer; inner = outer->begin(); }` – solely, the assignment to begin is UB, if outer already reached the container's end. So you need to detect this somehow. With contiguous memory, you could use a pointer as inner iterator and use `nullptr` as sentinel value. When reaching inner's end, you might just set the iterator to the sentinel and delay the assignment to `outer->begin()` until `operator*` is called.

Comment: With containers' own iterators, bad luck for sentinels, UB if comparing iterators from different containers, so what would you want to use as sentinel then?

Comment: @ALX23z `std::vector<Point>` might be inappropriate if you wanted to track changes to global set within the subset, too, or `Point` might be that large that you simply don't want to have copies.

Comment: `std:vector<int>` doesn't have any advantage over vector to pointer, it will break just the same as a vector of pointers on inserting elements (unless you *only* `push_back`, then yes, you are safer). And it is *less* efficient than pointers as you need indexing: dereference of vector + addition + dereference of pointer wheras a pointer just needs to be dereferenced (for the pointer we don't even have to know that pointee is stored in a vector...).

Comment: If you wanted to be safe for any change but removal of Points yet pointed to, then `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Point>> allPoints; std::vector<Point*> someSubset;` would be safe, `std::vector<int>` not... Using shared pointers in both subsets would be safe even for removal of points yet pointed to (possibly needing to check if a Point in the subset is still is in global set to prevent use of already semantically "deleted" points (not in global set any more), if use case requires). (All that still assuming I wanted to be able to track changes in global set in the subsets as well.)

Comment: @Aconcagua `Point` as the name suggests, is a small simple struct. Otherwise, you'd better use `shared_ptr` for more flexibility (for complicated and/or classes reliability and flexibility are more important than minor boosts to performance). `vector<int>` ensures safety under copy, reallocation, and serialization. Futhermore, it takes less space than pointers.

Comment: @ALX23z Point can be as small as it wants, if subset shall follow changes in global, you need indirection. I didn't intend to disqualify the vector of indices, it *can* be superior, but all depends on the use case. Vary these, and the vector of pointers *can* be totally valid solution as well (with shared pointers sometimes bringing benefit and sometimes not) – which is all I stated (or tried to at least) right from the start... Sidenote: negative indices would be pretty meaningless for containers, wouldn't they? So I'd prefer a `std::vector<unsigned int>`...

Answer (score 4):

Does something like this work for you (obviously it's a bashed out in 10 min kinda solution so don't expect the committee to insta-ship it in c++20 or something lol - it's just to give some ideas):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>


template<typename Pointee0, typename Pointee1, typename It0, typename It1> struct ChainedIter;

template<typename Pointee, typename It0, typename It1>
class ChainedIter<Pointee, Pointee, It0, It1> {
    It0 it0, begin0, end0;
    It1 it1, begin1, end1;
public:
    ChainedIter(It0 begin0, It0 end0, It1 begin1, It1 end1):
        it0{begin0}, begin0{begin0}, end0{end0},
        it1{begin1}, begin1{begin1}, end1{end1} {}
    bool operator==(ChainedIter& rhs) const {
        return it0 == rhs.it0 && it1 == rhs.it1;
    }
    bool operator!=(ChainedIter& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    ChainedIter* operator++() {
        if(it0 != end0) ++it0;
        else ++it1;
        return this;
    }
    Pointee& operator*() {
        if(it0 != end0) return *it0;
        else return *it1; // UB if it1 == end1
    }
    ChainedIter end() {
        auto newChainedIter = *this;
        newChainedIter.it0 = newChainedIter.end0;
        newChainedIter.it1 = newChainedIter.end1;
        return newChainedIter;

    }
    ChainedIter begin() {
        auto newChainedIter = *this;
        newChainedIter.it0 = newChainedIter.begin0;
        newChainedIter.it1 = newChainedIter.begin1;
        return newChainedIter;

    }
};

template<typename Cont1, typename Cont0>
decltype(auto) createIter(Cont0& cont0, Cont1& cont1) {
    auto begin0 = cont0.begin();
    auto end0 = cont0.end();
    auto begin1 = cont1.begin();
    auto end1 = cont1.end();
    return ChainedIter<
           typename Cont0::value_type,
           typename Cont1::value_type,
           typename Cont0::iterator,
           typename Cont1::iterator> {begin0, end0, begin1, end1};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<size_t> v(4, 20);
    std::deque<size_t> d(3, 200);

    auto iter = createIter(v, d);
    std::for_each(iter.begin(), iter.end(), [](const auto& elt) {
        std::cout << elt << ' ';
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I tried to make it work with different container types as long as they both are templated on the same object (which made sense as a kneejerk but maybe it can be enhanced to allow convertible types etc.). As seen in `main()` it works with `vector` as well as a `deque`.

My compiler version is:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So maybe I could use template guides of C++17 to not depend on that additional function for type deduction convenience, but this itself took more than 10 mins for me to type and then some more to sort out compile bugs; plus I'm sure it's got loads of other horrible-for-production stuff anyway :P

Answer (score 3):

- An alternative to implement custom iterator (which is really verbose) is to provide a method to iterate over all elements:

```
struct PolyLine {
private:
    vector<Point*> m_head_nodes;
    vector<Point*> m_tail_nodes;

public:
    template <typename F>
    void VisitAllPoints(F&& f)
    {
        for (Point* p : m_head_nodes) {
            f(p);
        }
        for (Point* p : m_tail_nodes) {
            f(p);
        }
    }
};
```

And call it:

```
PolyLine pol = /*..*/;

pol.VisitAllPoints([](Point* p){ /*..*/});
```

- Else, [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library provides `concat`view (which is lazy):

```
struct PolyLine {
private:
    vector<Point*> m_head_nodes;
    vector<Point*> m_tail_nodes;

public:
    auto allPoints() const { return ranges::view::concat(m_head_nodes, m_tail_nodes); }
    auto allPoints() { return ranges::views::concat(m_head_nodes, m_tail_nodes); }
};
```

That you can use:

```
PolyLine pol = /*..*/;

for (Point* p : pol.allPoints()) {
    /*..*/
}
```

Comment: `VisitAllPoints` has very limited uses, because you can't use it with STL algorithms.  But +1 for pointing out the *range-v3* library to me.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thank you [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539) for skilfully fixing the bug in my previous code, as indeed the `operator++` logic was flawed. I also changed the storage of the iterators to `std::array` to avoid unnecessary heap allocation.

---

This solution requires C++17, it uses a variant iterator type to accommodate for any kind of iterator, and it allows you to chain any number different collections.

```
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ContainerFirstT, typename ...ContainerRestT>
struct Chain
{
    // Holds an iterator of any given container
    typedef typename std::variant<typename ContainerFirstT::iterator,
                                  typename ContainerRestT::iterator ...> IterT;
    // Array of variant container iterators
    typedef typename std::array<IterT, 1 + sizeof...(ContainerRestT)> IterArrayT;
    // Iterator of array of variant iterators
    typedef typename IterArrayT::const_iterator IterArrayIterT;
    // Iterated type
    typedef typename ContainerFirstT::value_type ValueT;

    // Begin and end iterator of each container
    IterArrayT begins;
    IterArrayT ends;

    struct ChainIter
    {
        // Begin and end of container being iterated
        IterArrayIterT beginIt;
        IterArrayIterT endIt;
        IterArrayIterT endItSentinel;
        // Iterator to current element of current container
        IterT current;

        ChainIter(IterArrayIterT beginIt, IterArrayIterT endIt, IterArrayIterT endItSentinel, IterT current)
        : beginIt{beginIt}
        , endIt{endIt}
        , endItSentinel{endItSentinel}
        , current{current}
        {
        }

        bool operator==(ChainIter& it) const
        {
            return (beginIt == it.beginIt &&
                    endIt == it.endIt &&
                    current == it.current);
        }
        bool operator!=(ChainIter& it) const
        {
            return !(*this == it);
        }

        ChainIter& operator++()
        {
            // Go to next element
            std::visit([](auto& it) { ++it; }, current);
            // While there are elements to iterate in the current container
            if (current == *endIt)
            {
                // When the container is finished move to the next one
                ++beginIt;
                ++endIt;
                if (endIt != endItSentinel)
                {
                    current = *beginIt;
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        ValueT& operator*()
        {
            // Get value of current iterator
            ValueT* value;
            std::visit([&value](auto it) { value = &(*it); }, current);
            return *value;
        }
    };

    Chain(ContainerFirstT& containerFirst, ContainerRestT& ...containerRest)
    : begins{containerFirst.begin(), containerRest.begin()...}
    , ends{containerFirst.end(), containerRest.end()...}
    {
    }

    ChainIter begin()
    {
        return ChainIter(begins.begin(), ends.begin(), ends.end(), begins.front());
    }

    ChainIter end()
    {
        return ChainIter(begins.end(), ends.end(), ends.end(), ends.back());
    }
};

// Convenience factory
template<typename ...ContainersT>
Chain<ContainersT ...> make_chain(ContainersT& ...containers)
{
    return Chain<ContainersT ...>(containers...);
}

// Example
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::list<int> l = {4, 5};
    std::deque<int> d = {6, 7, 8, 9};
    auto chain = make_chain(v, l, d);
    for (auto elem : chain)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: [Fixed version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ba984a0f61c280). Your `operator ++` is wrong as it allows to point to `end()` of the intermediate container.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks a lot, now that you pointed it out the mistake seems obvious, but I was not able to figure it out myself yesterday.